# Counting days function in C

Tags: c, unix, data-structures

Here is the entirety of the code, I am still getting an invalid input every time I run the program.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int dpm[13]={31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

struct Sdate {
  int month;
  int day;
  int year;
} begin, end;

int isleapyear(int a)
{
  if((a%4==0&&a%100!=0)||a%400==0)
      return 1; 
  else
      return 0;
}


struct Sdate EnterDate(void){
  int d,m,y;
  struct Sdate A;

      printf("Enter the date(mm/dd/yyyy): ");
      scanf("%i/%i/%i", &m, &d, &y);

  printf("\n");

  A.month=m;
  A.day=d;
  A.year=y;

  return(A);
}

int  validate(void){
  if(begin.year > end.year)
      return 1; 
  if((begin.year == end.year) && (begin.month > end.month))
      return 1; 
  if((begin.year == end.year) && (begin.month == end.month) && (begin.day > end.day))
      return 1; 
  else
      return 0;
}

int count_days(void){
  int i;
  int days=0;
  int days_per_year = 365;

  if(isleapyear(begin.year)){ // first year
      if(begin.month == 1)
        days = dpm[begin.month] - begin.day + 1;
      else
        days = dpm[begin.month] - begin.day;
  }     
  else 
      days = dpm[begin.month] - begin.day;
  for(i = (begin.month + 1); i < 13; ++i)
      days +=dpm [i];

  for(i = (begin.year + 1); i < end.year; ++i) //in between years
      days += (days_per_year + isleapyear(i));

  if(isleapyear(end.year))//end year
      for(i = 0; i < end.month; ++i){
          days += dpm[i] + 1;
      days += dpm[end.month] - end.day;
      }
  else
      for(i = 0; i < end.month; ++i)
        days += dpm[i];
      days += dpm[end.month] - end.day;

  return days;
  }


int main(int n){
  printf("Please enter the first date then the second one\n");
  begin=EnterDate();
  end=EnterDate();

  validate();
  if(n == 1)
    printf("Invalid Input!!!");
  else
      printf("Total days between these two dates is %i\n", count_days());
  return 0;
}
```

The code is still saying that validate is always true making the output an "Invalid Input" and I've only been able to check the program count days scarcely but when I did it was pretty far off either a year or around 200 days.

Comment: You've got mismatched parens in that unreadably long line.

Comment: Should I make it a else if statement there instead?

Comment: That's an option. I don't personally mind long conditions, but I'd break it up into multiple lines and use indentation to show how the clauses are related. (In fact I discovered this while attempting to edit to do just that.) Here, I'll show you. Edited.

Comment: Sweet, I appreciate that.  But it's always returning true which is my main problem in the function.

Comment: Date calculations are horribly complicated. Unless it's an assignment, I'd use `difftime()`.

Comment: I would, but it is an assignment.

Answer (score 4):

Let's split that ridiculously long conditional up, and add some spacing to see what's happening shall we?

```
if( (begin.year>end.year) ||
    ( (begin.year==end.year) && (begin.month>end.month) ) || 
    begin.year==end.year) && (begin.month==end.month) && (begin.day>end.day)))
```

Obviously there's at least one missing parenthesis on that third line. Even *after* you add it, you're missing another pair of parentheses. Let's fix those two problems, shall we?

```
if( (begin.year>end.year) ||
    ( (begin.year==end.year) && (begin.month>end.month) ) || 
    ( (begin.year==end.year) && (begin.month==end.month) && (begin.day>end.day)))
```

Still, this is pretty hard to read quickly and understand. Let's split that up and add some sane spacing, shall we?

```
int validate(void) 
{
    if(begin.year > end.year)
        return 1; /* time travelling is not allowed. Yet! */

    if((begin.year == end.year) && (begin.month > end.month))
        return 1; /* you can't begin after you end! */

    if((begin.year == end.year) && (begin.month == end.month) && (begin.day > end.day))
        return 1; /* finishing before you start isn't allowed by the union */

    return 0;
}
```

It's impossible to answer the question about the "off by 200 days" without knowing more about those arrays, like `dpm` and those functions you call.

**Update**: You posted a bit of extra code; still not quite enough, but now my spidey-sense is tingling. Something tells me that the problem is in your `EnterDate` which accepts dates as "1-based" (i.e. January 3, 2012 is entered as 1/3/2012) but your arrays are 0-based.

**Update2**: Uhm... let's see here:

```
int main(int n){
  printf("Please enter the first date then the second one\n");
  begin=EnterDate();
  end=EnterDate();

  validate();
  if(n == 1)
    printf("Invalid Input!!!");
```

I didn't go much further than that. First of all, `int main(int n)` isn't valid syntax for `main`. Second of all, I am floored that you claim to have been struggling to find the error, by claiming that your `validate()` function fails... how do you know? you aren't even checking it's result!!!

How about this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("Please enter the first date then the second one\n");
  begin = EnterDate();
  end = EnterDate();

  if(validate()) {
      printf("Invalid Input!!!\n");
      return 1;
  }

  ...
```

**Update 4**: If you had bothered to add `printf` statements in your `count_days` function to see the execution, the error(s) would have *immediately* become obvious to you. Try this:

```
int count_days(void){
    int i;
    int days=0;
    int days_per_year = 365;

    if(isleapyear(begin.year)){ // first year
        printf("%d is a leap year!\n", begin.year);

        if(begin.month == 1)
            days = dpm[begin.month] - begin.day + 1;
        else
            days = dpm[begin.month] - begin.day;
    }     
    else 
        days = dpm[begin.month] - begin.day;

    printf("At first checkpoint: %d days\n", days); 

    for(i = (begin.month + 1); i < 13; ++i)
        days +=dpm [i];

    printf("At second checkpoint: %d days\n", days); 

    for(i = (begin.year + 1); i < end.year; ++i) //in between years
        days += (days_per_year + isleapyear(i));

    printf("At third checkpoint: %d days\n", days); 

    if(isleapyear(end.year))//end year
        printf("%d is a leap year!\n", end.year);
    for(i = 0; i < end.month; ++i){
        days += dpm[i] + 1;
        days += dpm[end.month] - end.day;
    }
    else
        for(i = 0; i < end.month; ++i)
            days += dpm[i];
    days += dpm[end.month] - end.day;


    return days;
}
```

Comment: I put up the main function and the array dpm.

Comment: @Linebacker15 I added a comment that *should* point you in the right direction. If it doesn't, then we'll need to see more code. But I'm tempted to ask, how are you debugging this? Have you tried checking dates that are one day apart, one month apart and one year apart to try and isolate specific failure cases? Or does it just not work and you throw your hands up and post on StackOverflow?

Comment: I've gone through checking dates like those but they all give me the invalid input statement which means that my validate statement is always returning one.  I've been messing with this for a while before I even attempted to throw the code on there.

Comment: @Linebacker15 did you try *my* validate function instead? Yours (at least as posted here) is horribly broken, and would not even compile. You may find it helpful to print the values of the `year`, `month` and `day` for the `begin` and `end` objects to see that they are what you expect. Have you tried to track down or debug this, or are you just randomly changing code and hoping it will work?

Comment: I did try your validate function instead of mine and it looked neater but mine still compiled when I was using it.  But even after I switched it to yours it was still sending me true for validate. I've also had it print out the values of both structures and they are correct.  I've been looking through the code to find out exactly what could be causing it, but have had no luck thus far.

Comment: I had before tried to put the validate function inside of the if statement but that part works now.  Thank you, also why isn't "int n" acceptable to pass back to main?

Comment: @Linebacker15 I updated my answer yet again; it should help guide you to figure out the problem. And the answer is because `main` has a **SPECIFIC** syntax defined by the C standard, and you aren't "passing anything back to `main`". As I said before, I am just *floored* that you seem to have put no effort into figuring this issue out and are just waiting for StackOverflow to solve it for you. This attitude may seem smart now but it will come back to bite you one day.